# Order by and group by and sum using SQL

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

What I am trying to do is get the top 10 most sold Vegetables by grouping them by an Id passed by parameter in a function and ordering them by the sum of their Quantity. I don't know how to use SUM or (total) quite yet but I thought I'd post it here seeking help. If you need me offering you anything else I will be ready.

This is my code:

```
   TheVegLinQDataContext db = new TheVegLinQDataContext();  
   var query =db.OrderDetails.GroupBy(p => p.VegID)
                             .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(p => p.Quantity)
                             .FirstOrDefault()).Take(10);
```

[And this is an image of my database diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6AZH5.png)

Comment: what is your question? ... what is preventing you from learning about SUM?

Comment: What does this have to do with SQL?

Comment: " grouping them by an Id passed by parameter in a function" -- where is the parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Group orders by Vegetable ID, then from each group select data you want and total quantity:

```
 var query = db.OrderDetails
    .GroupBy(od => od.VegID)
    .Select(g => new {
         VegID = g.Key,
         Vegetable = g.First().Vegetable, // if you have navigation property
         Total = g.Sum(od => od.Quantity)
     })
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Total)
    .Select(x => x.Vegetable) // remove if you want totals
    .Take(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this is not clear that you are passing what type of id as function parameter, I'm assuming you are passing orderId as parameter.

First apply where conditions then group the result set after that order by Total sold Quantity then apply Take 
LINQ query

```
var result = (from a in orderdetails
               where a.OrderId == orderId  //apply where condition as per your needs
               group a by new { a.VegId } into group1
               select new
               {
                 group1.Key.VegId,
                 TotalQuantity = group1.Sum(x => x.Quantity),
                 group1.FirstOrDefault().Vegitable
                }).OrderByDescending(a => a.TotalQuantity).Take(10);
```

Lamda (Method) Syntax

```
var result1 = orderdetails
                //.Where(a => a.OrderId == 1) or just remove where if you don't need to filter
                .GroupBy(x => x.VegId)
                .Select(x => new
                {
                    VegId = x.Key,
                    x.FirstOrDefault().Vegitable,
                    TotalQuantity = x.Sum(a => a.Quantity)
                }).OrderByDescending(x => x.TotalQuantity).Take(10);
```